# Find all possible subsets of cardinality C in a set 0-N

Tags: c++, set

How could you take a set of size N and print all possible subsets of a given cardinality?

> e.g. [0 1 2], 2--> [0 1], [0 2], [1, 2]

I could not find code for this and it took me some time to write, so I think it could be helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
void printSets(int N, int Cardinality)
{
        std::vector<int> nums;
        helper(nums, 0, 0, N, Cardinality);    
}
```

Using the helper function:

```
void helper(std::vector<int> &nums, int size, int index, int max, int cardinality)
{
        if (size == cardinality) //SET IS READY TO PRINT (base case)                                   
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < cardinality; ++k)
                    std::cout<< nums[k] << " ";
            std::cout << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        for (int i = index; i < max+1; ++i)   //WE LOOP THROUGH THE SPACES LEFT            
        {
            nums.push_back(i);
            helper(nums, size+1, i+1, max, cardinality);  //WE NEST AS MANY LOOPS AS THE CARDINALITY
            nums.pop_back();
        }
}
```

Comment: If you are asking for a better solution you should put this in the question part and not answer.

Comment: @TonyTannous I am really not. I used this for a project and I am done with it. I was just curious. That's why it is in a P.S.